# Need help on JNDI Connection issue

Tags: spring, apache-camel

Trying to connect two JNDI from the applciation,
Code below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<bean id="properties"
    class="org.apache.camel.component.properties.PropertiesComponent">
    <property name="location" ref="osfCamelPropertyLocation" />
</bean>


<bean id="defaultPropertyFileLocation" class="java.lang.String">
    <constructor-arg value="classpath:spring-properties-configure.properties" />
</bean>
<!-- List of property files in defined order, alows multiple config files -->
<util:list id="propertyFileLocations">
    <value>#{defaultPropertyFileLocation}</value>
</util:list>


<beans profile="!test">
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="osfPropsCamel"
        jndi-name="properties/orderFulfillmentServiceCamel" expected-type="java.util.Properties" />
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="amqEnvProps" jndi-name="properties/AMQ"
        expected-type="java.util.Properties" />
    <!-- Allows mixing jndi and file properties in Camel context(s). The last 
        entry in the list takes precedennce, avoid spaces between entries -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="properties" ref="osfPropsCamel" />
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="amqPropertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="properties" ref="amqEnvProps" />
    </bean>

    <bean name="prop"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
        <property name="propertiesArray">
            <list>
                <ref bean="osfPropsCamel" />
                <ref bean="amqEnvProps" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="bridgePropertyPlaceholder"
        class="org.apache.camel.spring.spi.BridgePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="properties" ref="prop" />
    </bean>

</beans>

<beans profile="test">
    <bean id="osfCamelPropertyLocation" class="java.lang.String">
        <constructor-arg value="#{defaultPropertyFileLocation}" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="propertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations" ref="osfCamelPropertyLocation" />
    </bean>
</beans>


</beans>
```

Following error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of type [javax.naming.Reference] to required type [java.util.Properties] for property 'properties': PropertyEditor [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.PropertiesEditor] returned inappropriate value of type [javax.naming.Reference]
[4/7/16 16:34:09:946 CDT] 00000050 SystemErr     R  at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:260)
[4/7/16 16:34:09:946 CDT] 00000050 SystemErr     R  at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:448)
[4/7/16 16:34:09:946 CDT] 00000050 SystemErr     R  ... 107 more
```